# How can I prompt the user for a save location from a Sharepoint page?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, itext, prompt, filesavepicker

I have a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441392/how-can-i-get-a-link-to-a-file-to-open-said-file), where I was trying to create a link to the location of the saved file (where the location and filename are taken care of for the user). Unfortunately, the link won't open the file, due to path access denial (as described in Update 4 in the link above).

What I *really* would rather do, if possible, is prompt the user for a save location (without requiring them to enter into an input text element something like "C:\Bla\Blee"); I don't think, though, that the tried-and-not-so-true (in this case) FileSaveDialog is available to me from a Sharepoint page.

Are there any alternatives or workarounds so that I *can* prompt the user for a location?

### UPDATE

I don't think this will work to try to save the generated file client-side, because it is generated (via iTextSharp) server-side.

### UPDATE 2

By creating a link to the file (as I have done, as hown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441392/how-can-i-get-a-link-to-a-file-to-open-said-file)), I can right-click said link and select "Save Taget As..." and do so (a "Save As" dialog appears, and I can save the file wherever I want). This being the case, there must be a way to invoke that same dialog programatically so that, instead of the user having to right-click, and then select a menu item ("Save Target As..."), they can simply mash the link and up pops, weasel-like, the "Save As" dialog.

So how can I invoke that obviously invokable dialog in response to a link click?

If see "Total and Payment Total do not match; Please enter the same amount for both values and try again." must redisplay the form (make a "show_sections()" function and call it after the save button runs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I browsed through your other questions and I just want to make sure that we're clear on a couple of things. *(If anything here is blindly obvious please forgive me, I don't intend to be insulting, I just want to make sure we're on the same page.)*

First, **client and server**. Anything server-side runs under the context of a user account and is *relative to the machine that it runs on*. If you say "save this to the desktop" using server-side code, then this is the server's local process's desktop which almost never makes any sense. If you are impersonating the logged in user, however, this might work except that you are saving it to the logged in user's desktop *on the server*. If the client and the server are running on the same machine and you are impersonating the client then this might actually completely work. Maybe.

Second, **Right-click, Save As**. When you right-click a link you are invoking a browser's built-in proprietary menu system. That system is browser and/or OS-specific and is not defined in any specification out there. In the 90's you might have been able to use VBScript to "send keys" and have Internet Explorer "click" that link but those days are long gone. The closest modern equivalent to this would be to write a plugin which I imagine you don't want to do (and would be browser and/or OS-specific).

Third, **MIME types**. Generally speaking, every HTTP response includes a MIME type which specifies the server's intent for the bytes being sent. These include things like `text/html` and `application/pdf`. When server-side code (ASP.Net) doesn't get invoked, for instance static files like images and CSS or even pre-generated files like your PDF, the server (IIS) looks up the file extension in a list to determine what MIME type to send. On the client side the browser uses the MIME type to determine what action to take. If it is `text/html` it (probably) renders the HTML. If it is `application/pdf` then the browser looks at *its* list of MIME types to see if any application has that MIME type registered. Most modern browsers have a built-in PDF renderer so the browser just passes the bytes on to that to render. If the browser isn't aware of that MIME it *might* ask the OS if it knows about it and has a registered handler available and if so it passes that through. If that all fails (possibly because a user such as me has disabled that specific MIME type) then either the browser just puts those bytes into the "Downloads" folder, it tries to interpret those bytes as text or it prompts to save.

Going a little deeper into this last one, per the [HTTP spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) (19.5.1 paragraph 3), if you send a MIME type of `application/octet-stream` in addition to a header of `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"` then

> the implied suggestion is that the user agent
> should not display the response, but directly enter a `save response
> as...' dialog.

This is what you are ultimately trying to achieve, right?

In your case, clicking the PDF link bypasses ASP.Net and IIS just looks up the file and sends the `application/pdf` MIME type along with it. One fix is to de-register the [PDF file extension from the system](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc770504(v=WS.10).aspx). This probably isn't the most portable solution, however. Similarly you could also just change the file extension to be `application/octet-stream` and you (might) get the Save As dialog.

What I would consider the best option for forcing the Save As dialog would be to create a handler of some sort server-side that forces the MIME type and Content Disposition headers into the stream and then passes the file's raw bytes. You could do this in a couple of ways, maybe with an [`IHttpHandler`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/873228/231316) (maybe even better [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/122/simple-file-download-protection-with-asp-net)) or possibly with just a single ASPX page that inspects the Query String. You'll want to perform some extra security and **definitely** make sure you don't allow path-like characters and commands in file names.

Comment: Chris, thanks for the great answer; but how would I "...just change the file extension to be application/octet-stream"? Does this mean changing it from .pdf to something else? If so, what?

Comment: In IIS, if you go to the MIME type section you can override the MIME type for that specific file extension. This [page](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap) walks through the general process.

Comment: I would note, however, that changing a system default via configuration often falls into the category of "oh yeah, I forgot I did that" in a couple of years which leads to hair being pulled out. I'd strongly recommend just creating a simple handler instead.

Comment: Yes, I don't hold the keys to the server configuration (IIS, etc.), so I need a way to allow the user to download the file to their machine regardless of what the server machine thinks about PDFs; I asked another question about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544178/how-can-i-make-a-file-generated-on-a-web-page-available-to-the-user-as-a-downloa

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17193199/231316) for a little background but remember that in one HTTP request you can return HTML to the client or you can return a PDF to the client, never both (at least in 1.1). If you want to give a pretty HTML message with choices then you're going to need to save the PDF server-side (or generate on-demand) and use a handler. If you just want to prompt to save then use `Response.BinaryWrite()` to write the contents of your MemoryStream's `ToArray().

Comment: Actually, I think it would suffice to just always save the file in a certain location on the user's machine without their interaction - just tell them that they need to have/create a folder named "GeneratedPDFs" or whatever. Perhaps FileSaver.js is what I need; I'm going to look into that.

Comment: Just to be clear, the server cannot dictate where it will be saved on the client's machine. Never. You won't find this in any spec past, present or future. The server is allowed to _suggest_ a _file name_ but browsers are explicitly told to ignore any path components. Browsers also routinely alter the _suggestion_ as sent by the server, too.

Comment: I have downloaded PDFs from the web that open a FileSaveDialog and allow me to choose where I want them to be saved; that's what I want to do.

Comment: Just to be extra super clear, to force a "Save As" dialog _in most browsers_ you just need to do what I said in the fifth paragraph about setting two special HTTP headers.